# Codeigniter official website open source code shows Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request) on Localhost

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl, redirect, localhost

I just cloned their project ( https://github.com/codeigniter4projects/website ) on my own pc and then used "php spark serve" to test it.
but the problem is, whenever I try to access it through "http://localhost:8080/", it redirects me to "https://localhost:8080/" and then the browser shows "This site can’t be reached-localhost refused to connect-ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" and also the console keeps saying "Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)"

I double-ckecked config files, htaccess and also php serve arguments but nothing seems wrong!

All the references I found through search were only about Laravel framework!

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: Their project relies on a SSL certificate being installed, but you don't have one.  Edit the $baseURL in \app\Config\App.php to remove the `s` in `https`